# RでTreemapを作成すると日本語が文字化けする

Tags: r, 文字化け

`data`には名詞(noun)と出現率%(freq)が格納されており、以下のスクリプトでTreemapを作成しようとしましたが、ラベルの日本語が全て（□□のように）文字化けしてしまいます。
解決方法を教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

```
library(treemap)
treemap(data, index=c("noun","freq"),
    vSize="freq",
    vColor="freq",
    type="dens",
    palette="RdYlGn", 
    fontsize.labels=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

当方のwindows環境では文字化けが発生しないため再現性が取れておりませんが、`treemap()`の`fontfamily.xxx`系の引数を指定することで解決出来そうな気がします。なお本回答は[からだにいいもの](https://www.karada-good.net/analyticsr/r-127/)様の記事を参考にしております。

以下、mac環境を想定した一例です

```
treemap(res3, index=c("Term","Freq"),
        vSize="Freq",
        vColor="Freq",
        type="dens",
        palette="RdYlGn", 
        fontsize.labels=10,
        fontfamily.labels = "HiraKakuProN-W3",
        fontfamily.title = "HiraKakuProN-W3",
        fontmaily.legend = "HiraKakuProN-W3")
```

Comment: @Ryo; スタックオーバーフローには、[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)、という機能があります、是非ご活用ください (存在に気が付いておられないご様子でしたので、紹介させていただきました)